# How to disable Up button when I navigate to a new destination

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I tried to disable the up button when navigate to a new destination, and make this destination as a new start destination.

```
// navigation.xml
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/firstFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
        android:name="com.example.myproject.FirstFragment"
        android:label="FirstFragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_firstFragment_to_secondFragment"
            app:destination="@id/secondFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/firstFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/secondFragment"
        android:name="com.example.myoroject.SecondFragment"
        android:label="fragment_second"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second" />
</navigation>
```

But when I navigate to secondFragment, the back button in TopLeft is always here and not disappear.

UPDATE

My main activity show below.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    private lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        drawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
        navController = this.findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment)

        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            if(destination.id == R.id.firstFragment) {
                drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_CLOSED)
            } else {
                drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)
            }
        }

        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, drawerLayout)
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, drawerLayout)
    }
}
```

BTW I want to disable the drawer toggle button in firstFragment, it also seems not work.

Comment: Where's your toolbar? In parent activity or each fragment has its own toolbar?

Comment: "Back button in Top Left" is called Up Button. It is not the same as back button. You need to provide more information, especially about Your AppBar

Comment: I set toolbar in one activity for each fragment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check [the doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#appbarconfiguration):

> Top-level destinations do not display an Up button in the top app bar because there is no higher level destination.
>   When the user is on any other destination, the Navigation button appears as an Up button . To configure the Navigation button using only the start destination as the top-level destination, create an `AppBarConfiguration` object

If you want to customize **which destinations are considered top-level** destinations, you can pass a set of destination IDs to the constructor, something like:

```
val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.firstFragment, R.id.secondFragment))
setupActionBarWithNavController(navigationController, appBarConfiguration)
```

About the `DrawerLayout`.
If the destination doesn't use a `DrawerLayout`, the Navigation button is hidden.

Answer (score 1):

In your activity:

```
// set action bar in your activity
setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
    if(destination.id == R.id.firstFragment) {
        drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_CLOSED)
    } else {
        drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)
    }

    // check if navigated to second fragment, then disable the back button
    if(destination.id == R.id.secondFragment) {
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)
        supportActionBar?.setHomeButtonEnabled(false)
    }
 }
```

Comment: I have not implement the toolbar myself, is it possible to work without with it?

Comment: In that case i think you should search for another solution. Couldn't you ask for access?